# Isolating records from large one line files

Tags: python, python-3.x, kml

I am using Python 3.3  I want to edit a google earth POI file (.klm) which is 1.4Mb on a single line. I need to isolate records of variable length which begin `<placemark>` and end `</placemark>`, check each for a particular word, throw away those without it, and save what's left.

Are there tools for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

KML is a XML format.

Use an XML parser to parse it (such as `xml.etree.ElementTree`, included in the standard library, or `lxml`).

You could use a dedicated package such as [PyKML](http://packages.python.org/pykml/) to give you a higher-level API to the information contained, although that specific package is not yet Python 3 ready.

*I did manage to run the [`2to3` tool](http://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) on the files of that project though, so your mileage may vary. The tests fail but the failures look benign (typical python 2 to 3 translation differences).*

Comment: Many thanks Martijn, I succeeded and it took only 6 lines of code.